# How to Create a List of Linked List in C++?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to create an array of linked lists in C++.

I want to create a linked list which can add/delete new student names and id.  Here is the structure of the node:

```
struct node
{
    char name[50];
    char id[50];
    struct node *next;
}*start=NULL,*prev;
typedef struct node node;
```

How to do this?

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node
{
    char name[50];
    char type[50];
    struct node *next;
}*start=NULL,*prev;
typedef struct node node;

void menu();
void insertion();
void finder();
void table();
void deletion();

int main()
{
    //node *table[57];

    while(1)
    {
        menu();
    }
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    int choice;

    printf("\nSymbol Table Menu\n1. Insert.\n2. Find.\n3. Show Table.\n4. Delete.\n");

    scanf("%d",&choice);
    //system("cls");
    if(choice==1)insertion();
    else if(choice==2)finder();
    else if(choice==3)table();
    else if(choice==4)deletion();

}
int Hashing(node *temp)
{
    int h,len,i,asc,sum=0;
    printf("\nHashing\n");
    len=strlen(temp->name);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        asc=temp->name[i];
        sum=sum+asc;
    }
    h=sum%57;
    return h;
}
void insertion()
{
    int index;
    node *temp;

    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start =(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp=start;
        printf("Insert Name: ");
        scanf("%s",start->name);
        index=Hashing(temp);
        printf("Index: %d\n",index);
        printf("\nInsert Type: ");
        scanf("%s",start->type);
        start->next=NULL;
        prev=start;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Insert Name: ");
        scanf("%s",temp->name);
        index=Hashing(temp);
        printf("Index: %d\n",index);
        printf("\nInsert Type: ");
        scanf("%s",temp->type);
        temp->next= NULL;
        prev->next=temp;
        prev=temp;
    }
}
void finder()
{
    node *temp;
    char key1[50];
    char key2[50];
    printf("\nInsert Search Key: ");
    temp=start;
    scanf("%s%s",key1,key2);

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if((strcmp(temp->name,key1)==0) && (strcmp(temp->type,key2)==0))
        {
            printf("FOUND\n");
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
void table()
{
    printf("\nFull Table\n\n");

    node *temp;
    printf("Linked list = ");
    temp=start;

    if(temp==NULL) printf("No list\n");

    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%s,%s -> ",temp->name,temp->type);
        temp=temp->next;
        if(temp==NULL)printf("NULL\n");
    }
}
void deletion()
{
    node *temp,*temp1;
    char del1[50];
    char del2[50];
    temp=start;
    printf("Delete Name: ");
    scanf("%s",del1);
    printf("\nDelete Type: ");
    scanf("%s",del2);

    if((strcmp(temp->name,del1)==0) && (strcmp(temp->type,del2)==0))
    {
        start=start->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    else
    {
        while ((temp->next->next!=NULL)&&(strcmp(temp->next->name,del1)!=0))
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        if ((temp->next==NULL) &&(strcmp(temp->name,del1)!=0))
            printf("\nNot Found\n");
        else
        {
            temp1=temp->next;
            temp->next=temp1->next;
            free(temp1);
        }
    }
    printf("DELETED\n");
}
```

Comment: In C++: `std::vector<std::list<T> >` or `std::array<std::list<T> >`.

Comment: While this has a lot of content, I still don't really see an attempt to implement the linked list solution.  I just see what could potentially be from a handout or even just another site on the web.  Show your attempt at linked lists.

Comment: Also, decide the language. C and C++ are very different.

Comment: @user3383733 i am trying both C and C++ for this so any language between this 2 will work for me. I will try with list. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of `node`s, and initialize each one of them separately.

```
node *array = malloc(NUMBER_OF_NODES*sizeof(node *));
int i;
for(i=0; i< NUMBER_OF_NODES; i++)
{
    /* this part is optional - you might want to leave some of the cells uninitialized */
    array[i] = malloc(sizeof(node)); /* notice that we need to allocate space for a node - not (node *)!
}
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but don't know where to put it. Kindly check my code and suggest please.

Comment: Your question was how to create such an array - well, where are you going to use it? If, for example, you need it globally - then the first line (the declaration) should be global and the rest of the code should be in an initialization context - create an `initalize_array` function and call it before you use the array for the first time.

Comment: At first i tried node *Insertion(node *start); but later changed it to global linked list. Since i am taking input for name and type in `void insertion()` so i think array should be call in insertion but again i need the `int Hashing(node *temp)` before inserting into the array because the hashing returns the index number.

Comment: Thanks got it working, for future reference what i did

I added `*array[57]= {NULL};`
for new name and type added `temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));`
`if (array[index] == NULL) array[index]=temp;`
`else array[index]->next=temp;`